# NFC with ACR122U and Android

Tags: java, android, nfc, acr122

http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/

I'm using the Android library linked above, and I'm trying to read/write NFC tags. The tags will have a format I know of (probably something like JSON). I am able to run the example app and see that the reader is working and detecting NFC tags, but how do I go about actually reading or writing them? The API is a little confusing. Any help is much appreciated.

So far in my app, I've figured how to get the reader state and reader type/name, but nothing regarding the NFC tags themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an instance of the `Reader` class (`com.acs.smartcard.Reader`) to communicate with the reader and NFC tags that are in range of the reader.

Depending on the version of the ACR122U, you will need either the `Reader.transmit()` method or the `Reader.control()` method (in combination with the control code `Reader.IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE`) to send commands to the reader. The relevant direct commands for enumerating and accessing tags are described in the Application Programming Interface manual (see [here](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf) or [here](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/1083/API-ACR122USAM-2.01.pdf) depending on what version of the reader you have).

Once you can access tags through the `Reader` object, you could implement the [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum.org/)'s Tag Operation specifications to interact with NFC tags.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work either. `responseLength` is always 0. It should not be.
That command is absolutely correct Read Card ID command:
`{(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x04`
and it works perfectly in Windows Java Example with the same ACR122 usb reader:

```
// Transmit APDU
byte[] command =  {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xCA, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x04};           
byte[] response = new byte[100];
int responseLength = 0;

try {
    responseLength = mReader.transmit(0, command, command.length, response,   response.length);
} catch (ReaderException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_text_view_response);
tv.setText( "resp: "+Integer.toString(responseLength) + ": "+ Integer.toString( response[0] ) );
```

Comment: Did you try FF CA 00 00 00

btw, did you manage to get Desfire UID in android? can share the code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the SDK provided by the vender ACS, you can try [Libnfc](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) which is a open source low level NFC SDK with LGPL license. You can build application upon the it.

Libnfc support ACR122U on both Linux and Windows.